# Is there any way to show ads on website by bypassing ad blockers?

Tags: ads, adsense

I just wanted to check my internet speed and when I went to https://www.speedtest.net/ I found the ads showing on the site even though I had my ad blocker switched on. This not only happens on speedtest, it's the same on some of the fandom subdomains too. And it's all adsense by google. I have been using adsense on my site too but I see no option to bypass the blocker, is there any way to do this?

Comment: 1. Some ad blockers controversially whitelist "acceptable ads" (example: https://adblockplus.org/acceptable-ads). 2. Ad blockers aren't perfect, particularly against sites that are trying to prevent them from working so they can make money to continue operating.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ad networks that have 'anti ad blocker' softwares. You will see ads if you have ad blocker on. For some websites is good to have ad blocker because they have many pop under, pop ups ads that affect your experience. But if a website have clear decent ads is good to not use ad blocker.